# Make the parent div block inner element from being selected

Tags: css, html, block

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span>Random Elements</span>
    <img src="RandomeImage.png" />
    <etc...>
</div>
```

I want to make it so that the parent div with its children elements act as 1 entity.
So for example, you may not select (highlight) a child element, or,  a click event anywhere (inside the div, on children or whitespace) triggers the parent click.

I have tried so many CSS (blocks, floats, ...) but i could not figure out the final solution.
I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for... You are talking about click event, but I do not see any event driven language in the tags? So I'm guessing it is Javascript, and if so, events bubble through the DOM so the parent would receive the click unless bubbling is stopped before by another eventlistener

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Comment: No @ZachSaucier, i ended up using Canvas to create my whole object instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use javascript to do this you could create a div with `position:absoulte;` to cover up the entire parent and all it's children which would then stop all the click events

[Here's a demo of that approach](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf9Zn/)

The added HTML element:  `<div id='cover'></div>`

And the added CSS:

```
.parent {
    background:teal;
    height: 500px;
    width:650px;
}
#cover {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; /* Same as object to cover up */
    left:0; /* Same as object to cover up */
    height:500px; /* Same as object to cover up */
    width:650px; /* Same as object to cover up */
    z-index:2; /* Higher than the object to cover up */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to select element just highlight it I prefer you can do ths by using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) (Javascript framework).

Here is code:

```
 $('.yourdiv').click(function(){
 $('.yourdiv').css("background-color","");
 $(this).css("background-color","blue");
 });​
```

Comment: Why add a bulky library simply to disable clicks?